# Carthage (iOS 13, Swift 5.1) - dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found

Tags: ios, swift, carthage, dyld

I'm trying to compile my library with Carthage, but I got this error:

[Carthage error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omGh5.png)

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _$s10RealmSwift0A0C5writeyyyyKXEKF
  Referenced from: /Users/-------/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/37B7A0EB-32DC-4A58-8150-5F5488160D70/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D66AFBC3-3C45-4BC4-928E-BF4EC0F70021/-------.app/Frameworks/-------.framework/-------
  Expected in: /Users/alexandrecools/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/37B7A0EB-32DC-4A58-8150-5F5488160D70/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D66AFBC3-3C45-4BC4-928E-BF4EC0F70021/-------.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
```

Do someone know why? And how can I resolve it?

Thanks,

Alexandre

Comment: I have just come across this as well, did you ever resolve it ?